Trying to install Qubes OS for for Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3
I'm trying to install Qubes OS Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 16IAH7, I followed the user documentation for rufus settings then tried Test media and install Qubes OS R4.2.1 option, also the second option using latest kernel but same results and I got stuck here: 

